# The integral of $\int | -1 | \ dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So yeah as the question says, how does one find this:
$$\int | -1 | \ dx$$
Now according to my understanding, the absolute value $ | -1 | $ would evaluate to 1 which then is basically just an integral of $1$. And it comes out as:
$$\int 1 \ dx= x \ + \  C$$

Is my reasoning correct? If not why?

Comment: looks alright. But don't forget the $+C$

Comment: As long as everything is "normal", this is correct, except that you should have a $+C$ at the end.  Is there some context for this, because it seems an odd question?

Comment: Oh yeah the goddamn C

Comment: @B.Goddard Um I got this in a pop quiz, and I honestly was expecting there to be some mysterious backdrop to this cause it seemed way too simple, but apparently it just is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course it is absolutely correct, usually we also add a constant $C$

$$\int 1 \ dx= x+C$$

to recall that antiderivatives differ by a constant, but this is not strictly necessary.